# El proceso no tiene derechos de acceso a este espacio de nombres

Tags: c#, webservice, wcf

Estoy realizando un codificador personalizado WCF siguiendo los lineamientos de este sitio [using-mtom](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/02/15/using-mtom-in-a-wcf-custom-encoder/)

Creo un web Service tomando un archivo.zip

```
    public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public FileResponse GetData(string value)
    {
        FileResponse response = new FileResponse
        {
            Filename = "Archivo de Prueba",
            Contents = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\temp\982A25FEEFBA.zip")
        };

        return response;
    }
}
```

los proyectos de clase se encuentran de esta forma:

[image: Services]

1. ++ CnsTestService consola donde ejecuto el ws
2. ++ ServicioTest servicio
3. ++ TextAndMtom clases para realizar el Mtom y Inspector encoder
4. ++ IISHost donde hospedo el WS

En la consola (CnsTestService ) tengo las siguientes lineas:

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string baseAddress = "http://localhost:62859/Service1.svc";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true });
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex");
        CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(
            new TextOrMtomEncodingBindingElement(),
            new HttpTransportBindingElement());
        CustomBinding mtomBinding = new CustomBinding(new MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement(), new HttpTransportBindingElement());
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), binding, "").Behaviors.Add(new IncomingEncoderInspector());
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), mtomBinding, "mtom");
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            MessageEncodingBindingElement mebe;
            string address;
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    mebe = new MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement();
                    address = baseAddress + "/mtom";
                    Console.WriteLine("Using MTOM to MTOM-only endpoint");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    mebe = new MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement();
                    address = baseAddress;
                    Console.WriteLine("Using MTOM to TextAndMtom endpoint");
                    break;
                default:
                    mebe = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
                    address = baseAddress;
                    Console.WriteLine("Using TEXT to TextAndMtom endpoint");
                    break;
            }

            CustomBinding clientBinding = new CustomBinding(mebe, new HttpTransportBindingElement());
            ChannelFactory<IService1> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(clientBinding, new EndpointAddress(address));
            IService1 proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(proxy.GetData("foo.bar"));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

            ((IClientChannel)proxy).Close();
            factory.Close();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to close");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

en el codigo del Service1.svc esta de esta forma.[image: service1.svc]

el error o advertencia en la consola se encuentra en la linea  host.Open();

Message=HTTP no pudo registrar la dirección URL http://+:62859/Service1.svc/.
 El proceso no tiene derechos de acceso a este espacio de nombres 
(consulte http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 para obtener más información).
  //~/App_Code/Service.cs    C:\Users\emiliog\source\repos\TextAndMtom\ServicioTest\Service1.cs
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CUAL Puede ser el Problema??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

la respuesta fue correr el netsh como dice el link

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/ user=Everyone
```

pero en la linea:

```
http://localhost:62859/Service1.svc
```

cambie a que escuchara al puerto localhost:80